# Why does a nontrivial $V \to V$ have a critical point?

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

Let $V$ denote the von Neumann universe, and let $j: V \to V$ be a nontrivial (non-identity) elementary embedding. The [critical point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(set_theory)) is the smallest $\kappa$ such that $j(\kappa) > \kappa$. The linked Wikipedia above indicates that any $j \ne \operatorname{id}$ has such a critical point; how might one show this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, by elementarity $\operatorname{rank}(j(x))=j(\operatorname{rank}(x))$. So it suffices to show that there is some $x$ whose rank is moved.

Now we can prove the following by induction:

> Suppose that $\operatorname{rank}(j(x))=\operatorname{rank}(x)$ and for all $y$ such that $\operatorname{rank}(y)<\operatorname{rank}(x)$, $j(y)=y$, then $j(x)=x$.

*Proof.* Simply note that $y\in x\leftrightarrow j(y)\in j(x)\leftrightarrow y\in j(x)$. $\square$

What follows is that if $j$ was the identity up to rank $\alpha$, it will either move some element of rank $\alpha$ to be of a higher rank, or it will be the identity on elements of rank $\alpha$ as well. Therefore if $j$ is not the identity, there is some element moved to a higher rank, and that rank is an ordinal moved up. The least such ordinal is called the critical point.

Comment: Asaf, the assumption in your highlighted argument is not strong enough to get the converse direction, since from $y\in j(x)$, you don't seem to know $j(y)=y$.  You should assume that $j$ fixes all sets of rank below $x$, rather than merely that $j$ fixed all elements of $x$.

Comment: Hmm, yes, you're right. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila, sorry for the late comment, but would you be able to explain a bit more why elementarity gives us $j(\operatorname{rank}{x}) = \operatorname{rank}{j(x)}$? Cheers!

Comment: @aidangallagher4: Because the rank is definable and $j$ is elementary.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm not sure if I follow: I know that rank is $\Delta_1$-definable -- so $\operatorname{rank}{x} = \alpha$ is absolute between transitive models. Also by elementarity we get $j(\operatorname{rank}{x}) = j(\alpha)$ (though I think this will always be true) -- how do we end up with the $\operatorname{rank}{j(x)}$ term though?

Comment: @aidangallagher4: If $\rho(x,\alpha)$ is the formula defining the rank, its complexity is unnecessary here (unless you only work with $\Sigma_n$-elementary embeddings), then $V\models\rho(x,\alpha)\iff M\models\rho(j(x),j(\alpha))$ when $j\colon V\to M$ is elementary (the context of $j\colon V\to V$ is again unimportant here). Since ZF proves that $\rho$ defines the rank function, and $M$ is a model of ZF, I'm not sure what else to say.

Comment: Oh I understand now -- cheers!